# Nuxt responsive menu does not load correctly when page is visited without refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am building a menu that is always shown as a row on desktop and a column on mobile. On mobile, it is only shown when a variable `showMenu` is true. I need the value always true for desktop, so I have this code in my script:

```
const showMenu = ref(true);

if (process.client) {
    calcMenu();
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        calcMenu();
    });
}

function calcMenu() {
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width < 1024) {
        showMenu.value = false;
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I visit the website, it works. However, if I navigate to a different page, it works, but then if I navigate back to a page that has already been rendered, it does not work. I have to press the menu button or refresh for the correct menu to show.

Here is the incorrect menu:
[image: Incorrect menu]

Here is the correct menu:
[image: Correct menu]

Here is my template:

```html
<template>
    <div class="">
        <div class="flex justify-between text-secondary flex-col bg-primary lg:flex-row fixed left-0 right-0 top-0 z-50">
            <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-between">
                <nuxt-link to="/" @click="() => { showMenu = false }" class="m-4 lg:invisible" >
                    <img src="/logo.png" alt="Magruders Logo" class="h-20 w-20" v-if="!showMenu">
                </nuxt-link>
                <button v-if="!showMenu" @click="() => { showMenu = true }" class="btn inverse">Menu</button>

            </div>

            <ul v-if="showMenu" class="flex flex-col lg:flex-row text-center justify-between w-full">
                <nuxt-link to="/" @click="() => { showMenu = false }" class="m-auto lg:m-4 lg:visible lg:h-20 lg:w-20 invisible h-0 w-0">
 
                    <img src="/logo.png" alt="Magruders Logo">
                </nuxt-link>
                <div class="flex flex-col lg:flex-row lg:h-20 items-center self-center">
                    <button v-if="showMenu" @click="() => { showMenu = false }" class="btn inverse lg:invisible p-0">Close</button>
                    <nuxt-link to="/" @click="() => { showMenu = false }" class="m-auto lg:m-4 lg:invisible">
                      <img src="/logo.png" alt="Magruders Logo" class="h-20 w-20">
                    </nuxt-link>
                     <li class="btn inverse">
                        <nuxt-link to="/" @click="() => { showMenu = false }">Home</nuxt-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="btn inverse">
                        <nuxt-link to="/funerals" @click="() => { showMenu = false }">Funerals</nuxt-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="btn inverse">
                        <nuxt-link to="/banquets" @click="() => { showMenu = false }">Banquets</nuxt-link>
                    </li>
                    <li class="btn inverse">
                        <nuxt-link to="/pub" @click="() => { showMenu = false }">Pub</nuxt-link>
                    </li>
                </div>

            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="text-black p-4 pt-24 m-4 flex flex-col items-center text-center">
            <slot />
        </div>

    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Don't use DOM event listeners + DOM modifications, use CSS media queries rather. You will have a hard time dealing with the whole hydration/state thing otherwise. CSS is also faster than JS, so that should be the tech to use.

Comment: @kissu Thanks! I am now only using JS toggling the menu on mobile and it works great.